# GPU out of memory in PyTorch with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: pytorch, ubuntu-20.04, tensorrt, yolov7

I'm trying to translate yolov7 model using torch to '.ts' file using the next code:

```
gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
traced_model = torch.jit.trace(model, torch.empty([10, 3, 768, 1280]).half().to(self.device))
trt_script_module = torch_tensorrt.compile(
            traced_model,
            inputs = [
            torch_tensorrt.Input(
                min_shape=[10, 3, 768, 1280],
                opt_shape=[10, 3, 768, 1280],
                max_shape=[10, 3, 768, 1280],
                dtype=torch.half,
            )
            ], enabled_precisions={torch.half}
        )
torch.jit.save(trt_script_module, "yolo_trt_script.ts")
```

But in the `torch.jit.trace` instruction it shows the following runtime error:

> *RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 38.00 MiB (GPU 0; 7.79 GiB total capacity; 6.52 GiB already allocated; 34.69 MiB free; 6.61 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF*

More details:

- SO: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 (8GB)
- Driver Version: 495.29.05
- Torch version: 1.11.0+cu115
- Torch-Tensorrt version: 1.1.0
- CUDA: 11.5

Two questions that arise are:

1. How come I could generate the '.onnx' file with a Windows 10 environment in the same computer but can't with Ubuntu (I have also tried to generate .onnx files)?
2. Is there a way to optimize the GPU load needed when translating the file?
   I have searched for a possible answer related to this problem I haven't found anything.

Ways that I have already tried:

- Close other processes
- Upgrade torch version
- Empty cuda cache

Comment: I don't know if I am right, but you are using a batch size 10 in `torch.empty([10, 3, 768, 1280]`. Try to use a batch size of 1 and see if it helps.

Comment: I've already tried with batch size 1 and it works but the purpose is maximize the batch size, what is really strange is the memory management of the GPU in Ubuntu and there has to be something wrong within it. Thanks for the comment!